# How to call MongoDB addFields in Spring Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongodb

I have the following type of object in my MongoDB

```
{
    ...,
    "name": {
        "en": "...",
        "am": "...",
        "ru": "..."
    },
    ...
}
```

Now I want to run the following query using Spring Data Mongo

```
db.categories.aggregate({$addFields: {'name': '$name.am'}})
```

where the `am` part in `$name.am` is the locale of the name, hence it must be dynamic. I looked through the MongoTemplate API, and as far as I found, there is no support of `addFields` operation. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [AggregationOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationOperation.html)

## Single use

```
AggregationOperation addFields = new AggregationOperation() {

    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new Document("$addFields", new Document("name", "$name.am"));
    }

};
```

## Generic

```
public AggregationOperation aggregateAddFields(final String field, final String valueExpresion) {

    AggregationOperation addFields = new AggregationOperation() {

        @Override
        public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
            return new Document("$addFields", new Document(field, valueExpresion));
        }
    };

    return addFields;
}

...

AggregationOperation addFields = aggregateAddFields("name", "$name.am");
```

Comment: what if "name" would be composed of two inner attributes, like "firstName" and "lastName"? "valueExpression" cannot be a simple String, could we use a Map<String, String> instead?